# reverse(): 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I'm facing a strange issue, *atleast for a python/django noob it's strange ;)*

**django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()** raises **'NoneType' object is not callable** when called from my **models.py**. When I execute the same line from shell, it works fine.

I have absolutely no clue why is this happening.

**Shell:**

```
$ from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
$ reverse('images:view', args=[1])
'/images/1/'
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    image_caption = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name='Caption')

    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date Uploaded')
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Date Modified')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image_caption

    def edit_image(self):
        return '<a href="%s">Edit</a>' % reverse('images:view', args=[self.id])

    edit_image.short_description = 'Edit Image'
    edit_image.allow_tags = True
```

**admin.py** *refrencing `edit_image` here*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from images.models import Image

class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['image_caption']
    list_display = ['id', 'image_caption', 'edit_image']

admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

**url i'm trying to reverse inside the images namespace**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='view'),
```

What I have tried?

- reverse_lazy() instead of reverse()
- kwargs instead of arg
- and things i don't even know properly. :P

**TRACEBACK**

```
Template error:
In template /home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_list.html, error at line 91
   'NoneType' object is not callable
   81 :         {% endif %}
   82 :       {% endblock %}
   83 :
   84 :       <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post"{% if cl.formset.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>{% csrf_token %}
   85 :       {% if cl.formset %}
   86 :         <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>
   87 :       {% endif %}
   88 : 
   89 :       {% block result_list %}
   90 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
   91 :            {% result_list cl %} 
   92 :           {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.full_result_count %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
   93 :       {% endblock %}
   94 :       {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
   95 :       </form>
   96 :     </div>
   97 :   </div>
   98 : {% endblock %}
   99 : 

Traceback:
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  139.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  123.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  78.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1196.                     _dict = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in result_list
  288.             'results': list(results(cl))}
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in results
  266.             yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in __init__
  258.         super(ResultList, self).__init__(*items)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py" in items_for_result
  185.             f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/VirtualEnv3.3.2/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/util.py" in lookup_field
  258.                 value = attr()
File "/home/ankit/Desktop/Python/Workspace/SnapShare/images/models.py" in edit_image
  30.         return '<a href="%s">Edit</a>' % reverse('images:view', args=[self.id])

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/images/image/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

**Python Version:** 3.3.2

**Django Version:** 1.6.2

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Full traceback where?

Comment: Did you set a variable named `reverse` to None somewhere?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams question updated. thanks. :)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich there's no such variable. added full traceback :)

Comment: Hey! In the traceback it says `urlresolvers.reverse`, but in the code you showed it says just `reverse`. And it says that `urlresolvers` is None.

Comment: Provided traceback differs from what your `models.py` say. Are you reassigning `urlresolvers` somewhere?

Comment: oh sorry, after your comment I tried accessing it using `urlresolvers.reverse` to make sure there was no variable `reverse`. I'll update the traceback. sorry for the trouble.

Comment: traceback updated. :) thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Your traceback still uses `reverse` and that *still* indicates that you assigned `None` to `reverse` somewhere. `reverse = <something that produces None>` is enough.

Comment: Earlier I had the wrong traceback posted, now it's the right one. That's my complete models.py excluding the imports. Not assigning anything to `reverse`. :)

Comment: Can you post complete **models.py** file, including imports??

Comment: @Arpit question updated :)

Comment: tutuDajuju's Solution 2 worked for me but i'm still curious why i'm unable to access `reverse()` in models.py? It would be great if anyone can explain that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

Using [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) in your model's method should do the trick (even though you tried it). This should allow you to use the callable when the urls are finally loaded.

### Solution 2

Move the model method to a ModelAdmin method, here is "copy-paste-ready" snippet:

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # ... the rest of the class ... #

    def edit_image(self, obj):
        return '<a href="%s">Edit</a>' % reverse('images:view', args=[obj.id])

    edit_image.short_description = 'Edit Image'
    edit_image.allow_tags = True
```

### Problem

Using reverse in the model is probably the cause for this behavior.

### Explanation

the models might be loaded too early (before urlconf is done), so the reverse method is yet to be defined.

Comment: Please read the complete question.:) Already tried that. :) Thanks

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Can you update your question to include the traceback when using reverse lazy ? It should be different.

Comment: I tried that, the traceback is EXACTLY the same except its showing `reverse_lazy()`.

Comment: interesting.. let me try and simulate this please

Comment: ya sure. lets hope you face the same problem O:)

Comment: meanwhile, please add some info, like which version of Django you are using and python (3.3 is it?)

Comment: beh, could not reproduce the issue. I used Django 1.4.2 (that's what was installed on my machine), from the trace I figured you're trying to use the field in admin changelist, so I created a simple model and modeladmin that used the field (same as you defined it), and both reverse and reverse_lazy worked. You'll need to provide more details to pin-point the root of the problem.

Comment: To verify the issue is indeed the location from which reverse is called, please move the model method to a ModelAdmin method (the only modification you'll have to do is use `def edit_image(self, obj):` and refer to id in reverse with `obj.id`

Comment: thanks, your suggestion did work for me, but I'm still curious why is it working on your system but not on my configuration. You should update your answer. Thanks a lot for your time and help :) 
I'll keep the question open for sometime, just to see if someone can explain this issue.

Comment: just edited my answer before I saw your comment :) . I'd love to know too, but please provide more info in your question (i.e: snippet from ModelAdmin, ver. of django used, perhaps directory structure and INSTALLED_APPS setting, etc...)

Comment: updated the question with python and django versions. the directory structure is the standard one, didn't change anything. A big thanks for saving my day :)